# Thermal circuit for shared heatsink

Tags: transistors, heat, basic, thermal, heatsink

I am following this [video from EEV blog where he talks about  calculating heatsinks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ruFVmxf0zs) and I noticed that he does not talk about multiple components sharing a single  heatsink. I have lurked around the web but I have not been able to figure out how it is done.

This is the thermal circuit for a single transistor in a single heatsink as shown in the video
[image]

How would the thermal circuit for two or  three transistors mounted in the same heatsink look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

If there are multiple pads, then the branch would happen after the pads and there would be three pad resistors under the transistor thermal conductances.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyNa9o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Great!, so if I solve this circuit I can calculate the heatsink I need to get the transistors at a certain temperature, right?. thanks!

Comment: Yep, as a reality check, you could compare it to the case of one transistor with 3x time heat, this result should be a lower temperature

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, the pads should be branched...